# Verify that $p \circ p=p$ but that $p$ is not self-adjoint.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$: (a) $\{(x,0)\}$
(b) $M=\{(x,y):x=2y\}$. Find an expression and a matrix representation for the oblique projection $p$ of a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^4$ on $M$ at a $\frac{\pi}{4}$ angle. Verify that $p \circ p=p$ but that $p$ is not self-adjoint.

**Definition:** An oblique projection on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ is a linear $P$ on $\mathscr{H}$ such that $P^2=P$. Unlike an orthogonal projection, P need not be self-adjoint.

Also self-adjoint means $P=P^T$.

How do I find the oblique projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is write an arbitrary $(x,y)$ as a linear combination of $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$ and then discard the $(1,0)$ component.
$$
       (x,y) = y(2,1)+(x-2y)(1,0).
$$
So the projection you want is $p(x,y)=y(2,1)$, which can be represented by a matrix acting on column vectors instead:
$$
       p\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right].
$$
You can check that $p^{2}$ is represented by the matrix
$$
         \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right].
$$
The matrix representation is not symmetric.

Comment: How is the angle being concerned?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : I'm not quite clear on your last statement. First, did you really mean $v \in \mathbb{R}^{4}$? And to what does the angle refer?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : How is $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ involved? And to what does the angle refer?

Comment: What does the angle refer?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : I guess they want you to project $(1,1)$ onto the subspace $M$ using this projection. $(1,1)$ is a vector an an angle of $\pi/4$ radians. That would be my guess. The answer is $(2,1)$ for this vector. I have no idea how $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ enters into this picture.

Comment: Oh $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a typo it is suppose to be $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: So if the space is $\{x,0\}$ how do I obtain a project (1,1) to the space? I know the first component is trivial to get but how do I do the same for the second space?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : The projection $p$ is the projection onto the subspace spanned by $(2,1)$ along the subspace spanned by $(1,0)$. If you want the projection onto the subspace spanned by $(1,0)$ along the subspace spanned by $(2,1)$, then that projection is $I-p$. And $(I-p)(1,1)=(1,1)-(2,1)=(-1,0)$. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: No. If you notice the problem states for subspace (a) and then (b). You were greatous enough to provided part (b) but not (a) so i am trying to figure it out

Comment: @UsernameUnknown A projection that is not orthogonal is determined by two subspaces $X=M+ N$, where $M\cap N=\{0\}$. The projection I gave you is onto $M=\{ t(2,1) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ along $N=\{ t(1,0) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Because of that $I-p$ is the projection onto $N$ along $M$. You can check this.